# Find all values of a partition column in Iceberg tables using the Java API

Tags: java, apache-iceberg

I want to query an Iceberg table using the Java API directly (without Spark) to find all distinct values of a column which is used as partition column. What is the most efficient way, starting from a TableScan?

I can use an iterable like this, where `table` is the Table variable in question

```
CloseableIterable<Record> iterable = IcebergGenerics.read(table).project(table.spec().schema()).build();
```

but this is too inefficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.